# How to fold 'grep -c <token> *.h *.cpp' into a single count?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, grep

I'm adding self tests to C++ code that ensures there are no `NDEBUG` and Posix assert dependencies (the back story below). The first test looks for inclusion of `<assert.h>` and `<cassert>`:

```
FAILED=0
COUNT=$($EGREP -c '(assert.h|cassert)' *.h *.cpp)
if [[ "$COUNT" -ne "0" ]]; then
    FAILED=1
    echo "Found Posix assert headers" | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
fi
```

Its producing:

```
************************************
Testing: No Posix assert

./cryptest.sh: line 1130: [[: 3way: value too great for base (error token is "3way")
...
```

When I debug it I see:

```
bash -x ./cryptest.sh
...

++ egrep -c '(assert.h|cassert)' 3way.h adler32.h aes.h ...
+ COUNT='3way.h:0
adler32.h:0
aes.h:0
...
```

So each file gets its own line and own count.

The [`grep` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) states the following. It does not discuss multi-line output.

```
-c, --count
    Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.
```

The behavior appears to have something to do with ***Output Control*** (form the man page) and `-l, --files-with-matches`. I also tried the `-L, --files-without-match` option. It produces a similar error.

My question is, how can I have `grep` fold the results into one count?

Or maybe I should ask, is grep and egrep the right tool for the job? If grep and egrep are not the right tool, then what should I use?

---

This is a Bash shell script that executes on every platform we support. Every platform includes BSDs, Linux, OS X, Solaris and Unix (and all the mobile variants, like Android and iOS). We have to work to get what we need in terms of tools like `grep` and `egrep`:

```
GREP=grep
EGREP=egrep
SED=sed
AWK=awk
DISASS=objdump
DISASSARGS=("--disassemble")
...

# Fixup
if [[ "$IS_SOLARIS" -ne "0" ]]; then
    IS_X64=$(isainfo 2>/dev/null | "$GREP" -i -c "amd64")
    if [[ "$IS_X64" -ne "0" ]]; then
        IS_X86=0
    fi

    # Need something more powerful than the non-Posix versions
    if [[ (-e "/usr/gnu/bin/grep") ]]; then
        GREP=/usr/gnu/bin/grep;
    fi
    if [[ (-e "/usr/gnu/bin/egrep") ]]; then
        EGREP=/usr/gnu/bin/egrep;
    fi
    if [[ (-e "/usr/gnu/bin/sed") ]]; then
        SED=/usr/gnu/bin/sed;
    fi
    if [[ (-e "/usr/gnu/bin/awk") ]]; then
        AWK=/usr/gnu/bin/awk;
    else
        AWK=nawk;
    fi

    DISASS=dis
    DISASSARGS=()
fi

...
```

---

***Back story***

Our project recently took [CVE-2016-7420](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q3/519) due to users building the project with other tools, like Autotools and CMake. The CVE is a direct result of omitting `-DNDEBUG` for release/production builds. The other tools don't configure the way we do, and we did not tell users either (1) they can't use other build tools, or (2) users *must* define `-DNDEBUG` for release/production.

Our [remediations](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/277) are cutting much deeper than "simply define `NDEBUG` for release/production" in documentation. We are [gutting all dependencies on `NDEBUG` and Posix `assert`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/277) so folks cannot accidentally get into the configuration. We are also requiring users ask for a debug configuration by defining `DEBUG` or `_DEBUG`; otherwise, they get the release configuration.

While an `assert` and the `SIGART` that follows is usually annoying in release builds, considered benign in debug build, and taken for granted, we observe:

- We are a security library (we handle sensitive information)
- A failed assert egresses sensitive information to the file system (core files and crash reports)
- A failed assert egresses sensitive information to platform vendors like Apple (CrashReporter), Apport (Ubuntu), Microsoft (Windows Error Reporting)
- Companies like Apple, Google and Microsoft cooperate with government to mine the sensitive information

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you're asking - do you need to do anything more complicated than replace `egrep -c <whatever> *.h *.c` by `cat *.h *.c | egrep -c <whatever>`?

Comment: Look at the output that `grep` produces and figure out what extra processing it needs.  One common approach for summing columns involves awk.  Please show some effort of trying to solve the problem

Comment: @steeldriver - a long time ago, we were told to not use `cat <files> | grep` because `grep <files>` is the preferred way to do things on Unix and Linux. If that's the solution, then please post it as an answer so others can critique it.

Comment: @jww Fair enough. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

*Note: the following is based on the GNU implementation of `grep`, however I think it should apply in your case as well*

As noted in the GNU `grep` manual (emphasis mine)

```
grep searches the named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the
given PATTERN.  If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given,
grep  searches  standard  input.   By default, grep prints the matching
lines.
```

Also,

```
-c, --count
       Suppress  normal output; instead print a count of matching lines
       **for each input file**.  With the -v,  --invert-match  option  (see
       below), count non-matching lines.
```

(and the default behavior is to prefix such output with the file name - although that can be suppressed using the `-h` option).

By concatenating your target files into a single input stream and piping that to `grep`, you should be able to override both these behaviors and get a single count without prefix:

```
COUNT=$(cat *.h *.cpp | $EGREP -c '(assert.h|cassert)')
```

IMHO this would qualify as a *useful* use of cat; probably what you have been advised against is [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: Perfect; thank you very much. My apologies for asking for the answer. There's too much I *don't* know about bash, so I try to follow the rules others tell me.

Comment: Having multiple file arguments is a good indicator that a `cat` is useful.  But you should say `cat -- *.h *.cpp` to prevent a filename that begins with `-` from being interpreted as an option string.

Answer (score 1):

[steeldriver’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310539/23408#310545)
(do `cat files | grep -c <token>`)
was my first thought when I read your question title. 
But I see that, in your script snippet, you aren’t using the count,
beyond comparing it to zero — i.e.,
you’re asking “how many are there?” when you want to know “are there any?”. 
Consider using `-q`:

```
if "$EGREP" -q -- 'assert\.h|cassert' *.h *.cpp
then
    FAILED=1
    echo "Found Posix assert headers" …
fi
```

Notes:

- You should always quote your shell variable references
  (e.g., `"$EGREP"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
  and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
  If you have defined `EGREP=grep -e`,
  that would be a reasonably good reason to say `$EGREP` without quotes,
  but see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350) to [Security implications
  of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408).
- `-q` (or, equivalently, `--quiet` or `--silent`) means “Quiet;
  do not write anything to standard output. 
  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found,
  even if an error was detected.” 
  This not only gives you the functional behavior that you want
  (i.e., the same functional behavior as steeldriver’s answer),
  but with the performance benefit that `grep` will exit
  as soon as it finds a match, and doesn’t need to read all the files.
- It’s advised to put `--` between a command’s options and its arguments
  in order to prevent a filename that begins with `-`
  from being interpreted as an option string.
- You don’t need to have parentheses around your entire regular expression.
- `grep 'assert.h'` will match `assert h`, `assert,h`,
  `assert3h`, `assertph`, etc. 
  If you don’t care, that’s up to you. 
  If you want to match only `assert.h`, grep for `assert\.h`.